# Angular - Como puxar uma requisição de outra página

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estava estudando angular e queria puxar as informações de fora da página principal, porém não estou conseguindo puxar o javascript por fora.

página repeticao.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
                        <td>{{ x }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("teste.js")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

teste.js ( é para puxar essas informações e jogar na página principal ) :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
            'Jani',
            'Carl',
            'Margareth',
            'Hege',
            'Joe',
            'Gustav',
            'Birgit',
            'Mary',
            'Kai'
        ];
    });
```

Comment: Você quer simular um http request ou simplesmente pegar a variável do outro controller?

Comment: Gostaria de pegar todos os dados que estão no teste.js e mostrar no repeticao.html
Porque mais para frente precisarei pegar as variáveis de um banco e o  $http.get("teste.js") será apontado para o banco, só que primeiro estou estudando como fazer isso por uma requisição mais simples para depois avançar mais

Comment: Você então quer simular uma chamada HTTP para que no futuro substitua para uma chamada do banco. Veja embaixo se a resposta te ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde sei você não pode fazer uma chamada `HTTP` para um arquivo `.js` local *( me corrijam se eu estiver errado )*

Você pode utilizar este site: [**MYJSON**](http://myjson.com/) para hospedar um arquivo em estrutura de objeto. Ele gerará uma `URL` para você simular sua chamada **HTTP**

Fiz um [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/m2EWv5OqQv8E4Knjvg1o?p=preview) de exemplo para você analisar.

Se você quiser fazer isso localmente com um `.json` , o processo é diferente. Eu aconselho utilizar a chamada **HTTP** real , porque você pode fazer os error handlings =)